# Is Tony Stark the natural son of Howard Stark?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man

My Question is whether Tony Stark is the natural son of Howard stark?

Comment: what makes you think otherwise? the general assumption without any hints of the contrary is yes

Comment: I think he is talking about Comics where we find out that Tony Stark is really the son of two S.H.I.E.L.D. Agents Amanda and Jude Armstrong, and the Starks are his adoptive parents. But in MCU, yeah he most definitely is the biological son of Howard Stark.

Comment: From Marvel's universe information (http://marvel.com/universe/Iron_Man_(Anthony_Stark) ) " Anthony "Tony" Stark was born to Howard Anthony Stark and Maria Collins Carbonell Stark, owners of the prominent US firm, Stark Industries. "   But wikipedia states "Anthony Edward Stark, the adopted son of wealthy industrialist and head of Stark Industries, Howard Stark, and Maria Stark." with no any reference though

Comment: @Vishwa in comics he was adopted. Not in MCU though.

Comment: @AbhishekMishra you are right..!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is Tony Stark natural son of Howard Stark?

Till now **YES**.

Marvel Cinematic Universe is not same as there comics counterpart, they took some liberty in changing stories. And comics retcon all the time films can't go that weird and zigzag way as comics running from so many years but films are not that frequent.

In comics Tony Stark is adopted by Howard Stark and his real parents are  [Amanda Armstrong](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Amanda_Armstrong_(Earth-616)) and [Jude](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Jude_(Tony_Stark%27s_Father)_(Earth-616)) but in films nothing like that mentioned yet.